# Using L hopital theorem

Tags: calculus, limits

I have just begun to read limits . In the second section of the first chapter,L hospital theorem is being used to find the limit of the function  . I have been trying to find its limiting value. I am stuck, I need help on solving this problem.

$$\lim_{x\to 0}   \sec{x}^{\sin{2x}}$$

Comment: $x^{\sin(2x)}$ or $(\sec(x))^{\sin(2x)}$?

Comment: @BabakS.  (sec(x))sin(2x).Second one

Comment: @BabakS. i dont know how to present the power value

Comment: Is the L hospital a place where sick limits come to undergo surgery and get better? :-)

Comment: L'Hopital's rule is for 0/0 type situations.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Yes, and they stay there for an indeterminate period of time.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo can't u help me sir?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form

Comment: I must comment that you have somehow got a very terrible book. A good book on calculus should start with limits, continuity, derivatives and mention L'Hospital's Rule as an application of derivatives. It can't mention L'Hospital's rule in the chapter on limits. I think such textbooks create an "intellectual fraud" on a grand scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{x\to 0}   (sec{x})^{\sin{2x}}$

This of the form $0^0$.

$\lim_{x\to 0}   \sec{x}^{\sin{2x}}=exp \lim_{x\to0} \frac{sin2x}{1/ln(secx)}$

Now use the L'Hospital theorem as the limit is of the form $\frac {0}{0}$.

Aliter:

$\sin 2x=2 \cos x \sin x$

When $x$ tends to $0$, $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin2x=2 \sin x$

The expression becomes

$\lim_{x\to 0}   (sec{x})^{2\sin{x}}= A$

$\lim_{x\to 0} (\sin{2x}) \log{\sec{x}}= \log_eA$

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\log \sec x}{2 \ cosec x}=log_eA$

Now use L'hosipital's rule:

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {(\frac{1} {\sec x}). (\sec x . \tan x)}{-cosecx.cotx}=log_eA$

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {tan^2 x}{-cosecx}=log_eA$

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {tan^2 x}{-cosecx}=log_eA$

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {tan^2 x}{-cosecx}=0$

$log_eA=0$

$e^0=1=A$

$\lim_{x\to 0}   (sec{x})^{\sin{2x}}=1$